# How to transform this Vimscript into Lua?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, vimscript-lua

Can anyone help me transform this into nvim.lua?

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
    \ pumvisible() ? "<C-n>" :
        \ <SID>check_back_space() ? "<TAB>" : coc#refresh()

function! s:check_back_space() abort
    let cpos = col('.') - 1
    return !cpos || getline('.')[cpos - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction
```

What I've done:

```
local EXPR_NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC = { expr = true, noremap = true, silent = true, nowait = true }

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<Tab>', 'check_back_space() ? "<C-n>" : "<Tab>"', EXPR_NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
```

But I don't know what's the function in lua to get the char at left of the currnet cursor pos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`:h nvim_win_get_cursor()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_win_get_cursor%28%29) will return a tuple containing the current cursor position, which you'll have to unpack to use. It takes an argument `{window}`, and you can use 0 to specify the current window.

[`:h nvim_get_current_line()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_get_current_line()) is the Neovim Lua analog to `getline('.')`.

Here is an example:

```
function check_back_space()
    -- get row and column
    local row, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
  
    -- get current line of text
    local linetext = vim.api.nvim_get_current_line()

    return col == 0 or string.match(linetext:sub(col, col), '%s') ~= nil
end
```

It's important to note the the column returned from `nvim_win_get_cursor()` is 0-based, while Lua arrays and `col()` are 1-based. So, in the following line

```
return col == 0 or string.match(linetext:sub(col, col), '%s') ~= nil
```

the first condition tests if `col` is the first column, and the second tests that the character ***in the previous*** column is white space, even though both use `col`.

---

See also:

- [`:h col()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#col%28%29)
- [`:h getline()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getline%28%29)
- [Lua builtin`string.match`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match)

Comment: I will study your well-organized answer after work!

Comment: How to check the entire line is composed of white-spaces?

Comment: wouldn't that require using lua's pattern matching?  https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html (the next page) shows `%s` for space characters

Comment: @job_start `linetext:sub(col, col)` takes a substring of line text. If you want to match the whole line use just `linetext`